# AspectJ ITD Generic Method Parameter Breaks Compilation

Tags: generics, aop, aspectj

I want to introduce interfaces to XSD generated concrete classes. First I need to show the working version:

```
public interface IBooking<T extends IChargeList> {
    T getChargesList();
    void setChargesList(T value);
}

public aspect IntertypeDeclarationAspect {
    declare parents:Booking implements IBooking<BookingChargeList>;
    declare parents:BookingChargeList implements IChargeList;
}
```

That version works but if I move generics to method declarations it doesn't:

```
public interface IBooking {
    <T extends IChargeList> T getChargesList();
    <T extends IChargeList> void setChargesList(T value);
}

public aspect IntertypeDeclarationAspect {
    declare parents:Booking implements IBooking;
    declare parents:BookingChargeList implements IChargeList;
}
```

The error message is:
`Booking.java:144 [error] The type Booking must implement the inherited abstract method IBooking.setChargesList(T)`

The interesting part it doesn't give error for `getChargesList()` method.

What could be the reason for that?

The related part in Booking class is like this:

```
public BookingChargeList getChargesList() {
    return chargesList;
}
public void setChargesList(BookingChargeList value) {
    this.chargesList = value;
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the source code of the Booking class, specifically the declaration of the `getChargesList()` and `setChargesList()` methods.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete I have added it.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with the last part first, a return type isn't part of the method signature, and so as `getChargesList()` has no parameters, the aspect implements that correctly. Its return type will not be bound in the second example, but that doesn't matter.

As to why `setChargesList(T)` isn't implemented, that is because 'T' is undefined. When an interface method signature uses a method-level generic type definition, that definition must also exist in the implementation. So this is valid:

```
@Override
public <T extends IChargeList> void setChargesList(final T value) {
}
```

But this is not:

```
@Override
public void setChargesList(final T value) {
}
```

And its that second example that AspectJ is generating

I'm afraid my AspectJ isn't good enough to tell you how to solve your immediate issue, but I hope that helps you work out what's going on.